# Facebook Login for business stopped working after updating iOS Facebook SDK. Error: Invalid Scopes: opened

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login

My Facebook login, in my mobile iOS app, was working great till I decided to update Facebook SDK for iOS.
Now it returns the following error:

[image]

Looking at my developers.facebook.com console I have the product "Facebook Login for Business" configured. Note that my app is connected to a company profile.

iOS code didn't change with the sdk update and the way I am asking permissions is the following:

```
loginButton = FBLoginButton()
        if let loginButton = loginButton {
            loginButton.permissions = ["public_profile","pages_show_list","pages_read_engagement","pages_manage_posts"]
            loginButton.delegate = self
            loginButton.center = CGPoint(x: self.view.frame.width/2, y: 160)
            view.addSubview(loginButton)
        }
```

Note: these permissions are the one needed to perform Facebook live stream and they have been all authorized.

I read in some threads that I need to switch to standard Facebook Login (no business) but I don't see any option in settings.

Do I need to change the way I ask permissions? Please help me if you have any idea!!

Thank you so mutch,

Alessio